# Why EF query returns null navigation property only for each first row for unique FK id?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

had the problem where EF query returned list where first item had navigation property null while other navigation properties with same FK had data.

For reference:

```
public class ShippingInfo{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Invoice { get; set; }
    public int AssignedUserId { get; set; }

    public User AssignedUser { get; set; }

}

public class User{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<ShippingInfo> ShippingInfos{ get; set; }

}
```

First step with linq query I'am getting list of shipments with pagination to show in front end (all good)
Second step with same linq query  in other method getting list without pagination to generate .xls file

linq query:

```
var query = await _db.Entities.ShippingInfos.Include(x => x.AssignedUser).ToListAsync();
```

In second case returned data have first row witn `AssignedUser = null`

Returned data:

```
{Id = 1, Invoice = "ABCDEF", AssignedUserId = 1, AssignedUser = null}
{Id = 3, Invoice = "111222", AssignedUserId = 1, AssignedUser = {User}}
{Id = 4, Invoice = "44455", AssignedUserId = 1, AssignedUser = {User}}
{Id = 5, Invoice = "qweq", AssignedUserId = 2, AssignedUser = null}
{Id = 6, Invoice = "qwe1", AssignedUserId = 2, AssignedUser = {User}}
{Id = 7, Invoice = "qeq1", AssignedUserId = 2, AssignedUser = {User}}
```

To fix this problem helped to add `.AsNoTracking()`
to second query. The theory I have that EF cashed first query and when executed second one response data was overwritten.
But I am confused why first rows of each unique UserId had navigation property null?

Comment: Please create a [mre]. It's probably _your_ code causing this, not EF's.

Comment: Make sure to await asynchronous calls: `var query = await _db.Entities.ShippingInfos.Include(x => x.AssignedUser).ToListAsync();`

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry but can not reproduce because actual code is corporate. Tried to reproduce maximum of it. Configs of dbContext and other are basic.  connection string

Comment: @YungDeiza sorry, forgot to add it to example, edited question as I am using async/await, thank you

Comment: There must be a difference between the code you show and the code you run, because the former doesn't reproduce the behavior you're describing.